# What type of attacks can be used vs MongoDB?

Tags: attacks, sql-injection, databases, nosql, mongodb

I'm starting to learn MongoDB and was curious if it was susceptible to some type of injection attack similar to [SQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Due to the nature of the DB, I don't *think* you can inject into it but... What other type of attacks can be leveraged against MongoDB?

Comment: You should watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy8-EYS3HeM
It tells all about nosql databases .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References)

[Client-Side Enforcement of Server Side Security](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html)

[Server-Side JavaScript Injection](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/14453905385/attacking-nosql-and-node-js-server-side-javascript)

Also MongoDB should not be accessible to the public.  It can be password protected,  and passwords can be brute-forced.  Client-Side js can communicate with MongoDB directly,  and MongoDB can authenticate individual users. However their authentication system is overly simplistic,  and in practice I have only seen this design fail.

Answer (score 8):

There are injection attacks against MongoDB, but these are largely mitigated by using proper data adapter libraries. Nonetheless, it's worth knowing that it's possible to inject in a few ways.

The first thing you've got to look out for is cases where you dynamically build a `$where` with JavaScript, using user input. By modifying their inputs, they may be able to alter your query. The second issue you've got to handle is injection of operators like `$or` (or parameters to such operators) which can alter the behaviour of the query. Both of these are mitigated by not using concatenation-style methods, but instead using libraries that work on data structures (e.g. JSON).

It may also be possible to escape the `$` that precedes an operator, in order to provide alternative operators. Make sure you're properly escaping keys if user data is used in them.

All in all, I'd avoid stuff like NodeJS for anything security-critical. It's not been designed with any form of security in mind, and it's a young project. If you're consuming MongoDB from a different language, that's fine.

For more details, see [MongoDB's FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection).

Answer (score 3):

First vulnerability similar to sql injection can be done in mongodb or nosql databases too. which would be mongodb injection.

Try to run mongodb on different port instead on default 27017 to avoid exposing. For official security practices you can always check out http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/

It tell security practices that should be used with mongodb server.

Mongodb Injection :

its fully describes here for php how mongodb injection can take place in phpwebapp if client side data is not filtered properly. Also solution to mongodb injection too

http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2010/07/mongodb-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-in-php-at-least/

Mongodb Null byte injection attack

http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/02/mongodb-null-byte-injection-attacks/

This is also a type of attack that is well written on this site , Have a look how certain fields in mongo collection can be overwritten using this method can this can be done in any webapp.

Answer (score 2):

The tool NoSQLMap includes a lot of functionality that directly targets MongoDB.

https://github.com/tcstool/NoSQLMap

There is an even-better video available that shows all sorts of attacks.

You will also find that NoSQLMap calls out to the metasploit-framework, e.g., exploit/linux/misc/mongod_native_helper

The project also suggests a viewing of this DEF CON talk -- https://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-21/dc-21-presentations/Chow/DEFCON-21-Chow-Abusing-NoSQL-Databases.pdf

Another tool is the Nosql Exploitation Framework

https://github.com/torque59/Nosql-Exploitation-Framework

And yet another on GitHub here -- https://github.com/cyberpunkych/attacking_mongodb

It turns out that MongoDB has some bad defaults (e.g., anonymous access, /var/mongo/f.txt or default file locations, etc), easily-guessed albeit modified settings, and [classic issues](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/25450/Mongodb-Mongodb.html?vendor_id=12752) as  well as [web issues](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2013/06/http-parameter-pollution-with-cookies-in-php/).