# How to test for NoSQL injections?

Tags: penetration-test, databases, injection, automated-testing, nosql

How to test for NoSQL injections? Considering that the structure (or actually the non-structure) of NoSQL databases is very different from structured databases like MySQL, MSSQL or PostgreSQL.

Are their known tools, payload lists, tricks or other common practices (other then using a creative hackers-mindset), in order to test if a application is vulnerable to NoSQL injections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very-basic NoSQL injection can be studied here -- https://ckarande.gitbooks.io/owasp-nodegoat-tutorial/content/tutorial/a1_-_sql_and_nosql_injection.html -- which is available from your testing tools if you install the purposely-insecure [Nodegoat application](https://github.com/OWASP/NodeGoat).

This blog posts a discussion and video around a Node.js framework called Meteor that uses a backend NoSQL database, MongoDB -- http://blog.east5th.co/2016/03/21/nosql-injection-in-modern-web-applications/

The princples should apply to other NoSQL databases. For more on penetrating MongoDB (and other NoSQL data stores such as Redis, HBase, CouchDB, and Cassandra), check out this StackExchange answer -- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96593/140 -- with another blog post specifically on MongoDB to check out here -- http://www.technopy.com/mongodb-injection-how-to-hack-mongodb-html/

For additional details with payload lists (aka wordlists), see this project -- https://github.com/fuzzdb-project/fuzzdb/tree/master/attack/no-sql-injection

Comment: There are a couple of MongoDB exercises with the [PentersterLab Web for Pentester Course II](https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester_II/course). It comes with a VM that you can practice on as well.